# The main effect will be non-significant if the interaction is significant?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interaction, feature-selection, linear-model

I am using linear mixed models to identify important factors, and it turns out that:

- `A`: significant
- `B`: not significant
- `A`×`B`: significant

Does it mean that because `A`×`B` shows that the effect of `A` depends on the effect of `B`, only the effect of `A` is not actually significant?

I have read many sources, and they seem to suggest that if the effect of `A`×`B` is significant, then we cannot interpret that the effect of `A` is significant on our dependent variable. Am I understanding right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you read is correct. If the interaction is significant, interpreting either main effect, whether significant or not, is basically pointless (and misleading). The reason is that when $A$ and $B$ are involved in an interaction, the coefficient for $A$ is the effect of $A$ **when $B=0$**; in other words, the effect is conditional on the value of $B$, and is not a main effect. Similarly, the coefficient for $B$ is the effect of $B$ **when $A=0$**.

The fact that $A$ is significant merely means that $A$ has an effect when $B=0$. Similarly, the fact that $B$ is not significant merely means that $B$ doesn't have an effect when $A=0$, though it probably does have an effect for other values of $A$; *this is precisely why the interaction is significant*.

What you would need to do is look at simple slopes, which shows the significance of the $A$ effect as a function of the $B$ variable. You need to determine at which values of $B$ does $A$ have an effect, and vice-versa. Kris Preacher provides [an online tool](http://www.quantpsy.org/interact/hlm2.htm) to decompose 2-way interactions in linear mixed models.

Comment: Sorry so it means that I cannot interpret A as having a main effect for DV? In other words, if the results are just like this, I should ignore the main effect of A?

Comment: You should decompose the interaction. You can interpret the significant A effect as "A has an effect *when B=0*". If you want the significance of the A effect for other values of B (which you surely do), then you need to look at simple slopes (i.e. decompose the interaction). You can do this by using the online tool that I link to in my answer.

Comment: Ok I think I get what you mean. The effect of A is conditional by B. Thanks very much Patrick Coulombe.

Comment: Oh Patrick Coulombe, could I ask if I would like to know only effect of A to DV without any condition, then I will have to remove B and B*A from this model, right?

Comment: You will have to remove B*A (and not necessarily B). If you retain B without B*A, the interpretation of the A effect is the effect of A controlling for B (holding B constant). In that case, the A effect is interpretable as a main effect (its interpretation is not conditional on the value of B).

Comment: Alright. This is much clearer to me now. Thanks you very much Patrick coulombe. I really appreciate your helps.